# Selenium -- Unable to locate element

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing

I try to get the element using `cssSelector`, but always got an error: Unable to locate the element. Any advice? Kindly help! You can refer to my code Thanks a lot!

```
driver.switchTo().frame("contentViewInsertDialog_ctl00_ctl00_contentView_frontendPagesCreate_ctl00_ctl00_sections_mainSection_0_ctl00_0_ctl00_0_fields_0_PagesNameFieldControl_0_ctl00_0_ctl00_0_textBox_write_0");

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#contentViewInsertDialog$ctl00$ctl00$contentView$frontendPagesCreate$ctl00$ctl00$sections$ctl00$mainSection$ctl00$ctl00$fields$ctl01$PagesNameFieldControl$ctl00$ctl00$textBox_write")).sendKeys("Testing Page for CWP Testing");
```

Comment: Given info is not enough, try to provide more code like an html or some website link from where you want to locate that element.

Comment: @AliCSE Hi, i using the dev portal of my office. So, i cant share the link. But, regarding to my question. I read some article, that we need to switch iframe. that is right?

Comment: @FadhilPratama, post just portion of HTML related to your code.

Comment: Yes, if your element is present inside the `iframe` or `frame` then you need to switch the frame before doing any operation on that element.

Comment: @Fadhil Pratama, post the error that you are getting so it maybe helpful to resolve your error.

Comment: If I were you, I would work on finding the iFrame as a WebElement first.
`var frameElement = driver.findElement(By.tagName(“iframe“))` then use `driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement);`

Comment: @MichielBugher thank you! but I want to ask. So we dont need to put the element id for IFrame?

Comment: @FadhilPratama You absolutely can put the Id if you want to. I would recommend it if you have multiple iFrames on the page.

Comment: @FadhilPratama Did this work for you?

Comment: @MichielBugher thanks a lot for your help! i will try tomorrow. because our office server turned off when night. i will give u an update!

Comment: @AliCSE thanks a lot for ur help!!!